# C++ Vectors and OpenGL

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opengl

I have a strange error with the OpenGL code I am writing. As a test, I'm creating a vector of spheres and using push_back(s1). I'm adding multiple spheres to the vector. However, when I run the program it only draws the sphere that was most recently pushed into the vector.

```
#include "Sphere.h";
#include <iostream>;
#include <vector>;
using namespae std;

vector<Sphere> spheres;
Sphere s1 = Sphere(1.0, "One");
Sphere s2 = Sphere(2.0, "Two");
Sphere s3 = Sphere(3.0, "Three");

void init(void) {
    spheres.push_back(s1);
    spheres.push_back(s2);
    spheres.push_back(s3);

    for each(Sphere s in spheres) {
        cout << s.getName() << "\n";
    }
}

// OTHER CODE OMMITED

void display(void) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glPushMatrix();

    for each(Sphere in s) {
        s.draw();
    }

    glPopMatrix();
}
```

Obviously there is a main method in there where all the GL stuff is setup and I know that there is no issue there.

So the sphere has its own draw method. Now the interesting part is that in the console it outputs:

```
Three
Three
Three
```

and proceeds to draw s3, three times to the screen.

So my question is: why is it only drawing the last item in the vector three times? I have also tried using an iterator and a normal for loop but they all produce the same result.

Anyone have an idea?

**EDITS**

getName() function:

```
string Sphere::getName() {
    return name;
}
```

iterator for vector:

```
vector<Sphere>::iterator it;
void display() {
    for(it = planets.begin(); it != planets.end(); ++it) {
        it->draw();
    }
}
```

draw code in Sphere:

```
GLdouble r = 0.0;
GLfloat X = 0.0f;
string name = " ";

Sphere::Sphere(GLdouble ra, GLfloat x, string n)
{
    r = ra;
    X = pos;
    name = n;
}


Sphere::~Sphere(void)
{
}

void Sphere::draw(void) 
{
    glutSolidSphere(r, 10, 8);
    glTranslatef(X, 0.0, 0.0);
}

string Sphere::getName(void)
{
    return name;
}
```

Comment: The error appears to be in your definition of `Sphere`.

Comment: Don't write `;` after #includes.

Comment: I would also be interested in seeing the C++ code for `for each(Sphere s in spheres) { cout << s.getName() << "\n"; }`

Comment: code in getName() = `return name` and name is declared as a string. It even draws s3 three times.

Comment: what is `for each(Sphere s in spheres)`? Please show us the real code.

Comment: spheres is the vector of spheres `vector<Sphere> spheres`

Comment: no, @Jim, how does your loop look like?

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic: VC++ expansion. Hooray. /sarcasm.

Comment: Please post code that compiles. This is simply not valid C++.

Comment: @Jim And **please** learn to use `code` button. That's the last time I am fixing your indentation for you

Comment: For those who don't know the evil `for each` extension in Visual Studio: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/arich/archive/2004/09/08/227139.aspx While it isn't valid C++, it ___will compile___ in his VC10.

Comment: @Zeta: yaahooo!! however, the docs say that it is not c++ but only for c++/CLI so I am not sure if it can work on `vector`

Comment: This code will not compile. Even disregarding the VC++ specific extenstions. Show us your actual code.

Comment: You haven't declared sphere::name as static or something, have you?

Comment: what is `s` in `display` function? you call `for each(Sphere in s) s.draw(); `, i.e. you `draw` the collection you iterate over. Please don't make us guess the real code.

Comment: @JasonD no I haven't. I just don't understand why the whole vector gets replaced each time a new element is pushed to it. So if I comment out the `push_back(s3)` then only `Two Two` appears and sphere two gets drawn.

Comment: @JimBean How come you failed to address any of the other comments? SHOW THE REAL CODE. `using namespae std;` is not your real code, and neither is `for each(Sphere in s)`. Those don't even compile, your program wouldn't run if that were your code. What's so hard about copy&pasting?

Comment: Where's the `Sphere` constructor getting `pos` from?

Comment: @JimBean Declaring 'name' as a global rather than a class member would come under the 'or something' part of my suggestion :)

Answer (score 5):

The problem appears to be that you have defined 3 global variables in Sphere.cpp, instead of class member variables.  So every time the constructor runs, it overwrites the previous values, and you only see the last object constructed.

The solution is to declare them as members.

In Sphere.h, inside the class definition for Sphere, put

```
class Sphere { 
   // constructors, your current functions, and so on...
  private:
   GLdouble r;
   GLfloat X;
   string name;
}
```

Finally, questions like this are an example of why it's important that you provide a small example that demonstrates the problem.  The first reason is it makes it easier for us to determine the source of the problem.  The second is that is that it makes you examine your code in small parts.  Once you've isolated the problem, it is more likely you'll be able to recognize the problem on your own.